# Parse a multi level json in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this json file and I would like to get back "host_name" values for all items. Below, my php code, I tried some things, using true to decode json in an array or without it and use a `foreach()`, but I can't do it.

```
{
    "href": "https://webservice:8080",
    "items": [
        {
            "Hosts": {
                "cluster_name": "cluster1",
                "host_name": "server1"
            },
            "href": "https://server1:8080"
        },
        {
            "Hosts": {
                "cluster_name": "cluster1",
                "host_name": "server2"
            },
            "href": "https://server2:8080"
        },
        {
            "Hosts": {
                "cluster_name": "cluster1",
                "host_name": "server3"
            },
            "href": "https://server3:8080"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my php code. Would like to do it as simple as possible. My goal is to use last values of a json ('host_name') to display all of them.

```
<?php
        $content = file_get_contents("test.json");
        $content = utf8_encode($content);
        $result = json_decode($content, true);
        var_dump($result);
        echo "<br><br><br>";

        #echo $result["items"]["Hosts"][0]["host_name"];

        foreach($result as $r) {
                echo $r['items']['Hosts']['cluster_name'].'<br>';
        }
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just looping over the wrong array, it should be

```
foreach($result['items'] as $item) {
    echo $item['Hosts']['host_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$result` need to be `$result['items']`

```
foreach($result['items'] as $r) {
  echo $r['Hosts']['cluster_name'];
  echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/837593

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, you are looping through the wrong array. You can loop through the object like this as well:

```
$obj = json_decode(utf8_encode(file_get_contents("test.json")));
foreach($obj->items as $item)
{
    var_dump($item->Hosts->host_name);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work in that way. I mean it works, but results are shown in the same line with prefix string(X)

Comment: @tonio94 I've used `var_dump()`. Simply use `echo $item->Hosts->host_name . '<br>'`;  in loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show an alternative method, you can use `array_column()` and `implode()` to omit the trailing `<br>` that will be displayed with the foreach loop methods.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e3686ba1583063479e1f94bbff8cbaafde695451))

```
$items=json_decode($json,true)['items'];
echo implode("<br>",array_column(array_column($items,'Hosts'),'host_name'));
```

Output:

```
server1<br>server2<br>server3
```